# Confused about data analytics vs business intelligence course curriculum

Tags: powerbi, data-science, business-intelligence, data-analysis, informatica

I'm fixing to pursue a career as a software business intelligence(BI) expert. I've already started taking classes in Informatica and loving it so far. I've been enquiring from an online training institute for a good package and they gave me a good deal but their course curriculum is what concerned me - it seemed to be more a data analyst/scientist geared course, rather than a pure BI expert/developer course curriculum! The red flag for me was that their curriculum did not contain any data warehousing courses, which is critical to be a BI developer! Here are the courses that I was offered (under the guise of BI master's program, but what seems to be a re-packaged data scientist/analyst master's program):

```
 BUSINESS ANALYTICS EXPERT:
 ***************************
 1. MS Excel
 2. Data Science with R OR Data Science with SAS
 3. Tableau
 4. Data science with Python
 5. Electives (Power BI/Talend/Qliksense/Informatica)
```

Am I totally off-base in my assumption that the above courses are geared for someone wanting to be a data scientist, and not a BI developer? Shouldn't data warehousing be one of the major courses above? What other courses would need to be added in there (unix scripting for automating Informatica jobs?) to make it a TRUE Business Intelligence curriculum? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like a good mix of traditional BI and data science. Most of your real learning is on the job. Courses don't teach you much that is practical (going by the questions I see on here!). If you're just starting out your DW work will most likely be on keeping an existing DW running with a bit of "data science" thrown in to keep the business happy. It's unlikely you will be building a new DW from scratch. There are dozens of different technologies approaches for building DW's. Not just Unix and Informatica. Truly valuable job skills are flexibility, problem solving and communication.

Comment: This looks like a better fit for another site like Quora. This site is for specific questions, and yours is asking for opinion of the curriculum design.